# Is the unpublished Google Suggest Queries API VALID for use

Tags: autocomplete, google-suggest

Does anyone know if it's legal to use Google suggestqueries in a commercial product ?

As I'm using the open stream of the ajax jsonp request https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callb.... in searchengine based product.

Comment: Have you read the terms and conditions? Some are located here: https://www.google.com/work/gsa/terms_v13.html

Comment: SURE i did !!.. but nothing related to my concern!.. Thanks

Comment: This is a legal question that has nothing to do with coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it can't be legally used and the search team changes the endpoint every now and then so apps can't abuse it , however there are wrapper services which emulate / Gather data from the endpoints through their own means - http://keywordtool.io/api is an example of that

Comment: Thanks :)... But if it's not legal for public use.. Any ideas why google allow any origin to use these endpoints ?!